# Delphi setting up AdoConnection in runtime gives access violation

Tags: database, delphi

I'm trying to code a function that creates a `TADOQuery` dynamically. With this function, I'm able to change its `SQL.Text` property in the parameter of the function. How my function call should work:

```
procedure TDlgMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Q: TADOQuery;
begin
  Q := NewQuery('select * from Utenti');
  Q.Open;
end;
```

Here the code of the function and a screenshot of the access violation error, is there a way to solve this?

```
function NewQuery(Conn: TADOConnection; SQL: String): TADOQuery; overload;
function NewQuery(SQL: String): TADOQuery; overload;


function TDMDB.NewQuery(Conn: TADOConnection; SQL: String): TADOQuery;
begin
  Result := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  Result.Connection := Conn;
  Result.SQL.Text := SQL;
end;

function TDMDB.NewQuery(SQL: String): TADOQuery;
begin
  Result := NewQuery(DBConn, SQL);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: The low number in the address makes it look like you're calling a method on an object reference that is nil. So what is DBConn? Where is it coming from, and what does it return? On which line do you actually get that exception?
Side note: TAdoQuery won't automatically be freed. You need to free it after you're done with it, otherwise you'll have big memory leaks, and potentially even keep cursors open to your database.

Comment: DBConn is my ADOConnection object, configured like this: connected = True, connectionstring is not empty, loginprompt = false
I get that exception in this line: Result := NewQuery(DBConn, SQL);

Comment: @MattiTheMaestro: Yes, but where do you get the connection from? Do you create it yourself (`DBConn := TADOConnection.Create(...)`) or is it a component you have dropped on you form? Also, you should be able to pinpoint the line of code more precisely. Put a breakpoint (F5) on `Result := NewQuery(DBConn, SQL)` and run your app. Hover the cursor above `DBConn` to see if it is assigned or `nil`. Then press F7 to step into `NewQuery`. Keep pressing F7 to pinpoint the precise line.

Comment: You haven't shown all the code. Your newquery implementations seem to be part of a datamodule. We cannot see if it was created prior the tdlgmain call (that seems to be a different one). So, it could be that you haven't instantiated the model, or that model is not completely initialized (for example, the connection is nil). So it would be better to follow the execution using the debugger.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I dropped the connection in my form

Comment: @MattiTheMaestro The code you have shown suggests that `DBConn` is coming from a `TDataModule`, not a `TForm`. Is it possible that the `TDataModule` has its own `DBConn` member that is not being assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the `TDataModule` is not yet created at the time you attempt to use it to create the query via `DMDB.NewQuery()`.

The reason for the error is two folded.

First, when using the IDE to first create a form (`DlgMain: TDlgMain` in your case) and then a data module (`TDMDB: TDataModule`). This places the module creation after the form creation in the project file (`.dpr`) as folllows: (to see the `.dpr` file, select menu `Project - View source`)

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TDlgMain, DlgMain);
  Application.CreateForm(TDMDB, DMDB);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Secondly, as you attempt to create the connection already in the main forms `OnCreate()` event, when the data module is not yet created, the result is the AV you see.

You can correct the error by moving the creation of your data module before the creation of your main form:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TDMDB, DMDB);    // Create this before the form
  Application.CreateForm(TDlgMain, DlgMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

*A side note, in case you wonder:*

You may be aware that the first form created via `Application.CreateForm()` becomes the main form, and that is still valid. The data module is not a form, and thus your `DlgMain` is still the first created form and becomes the main form.